# My UnrealEngine 5 game won't open after I package it

Tags: unreal-engine5

I went through the project settings and did everything I need prior to packaging, packaged it and now when I got to open I get the little blue loading circle on my cursor for a second, disappears and nothing happens.

Here's the warnings I get, the path it's trying to find doesn't exist and I don't know why it's being called anyways.

```
LogUObjectGlobals: Warning: Failed to find object 'Class None.Physics'
LogLinker: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventFix': Can't find file.
LogLinker: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventFix': Can't find file.
LogUObjectGlobals: Warning: Failed to find object 'Object /Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventFix.HorrorEventFix'
LogLinker: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventsMasterFix': Can't find file.
LogLinker: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventsMasterFix': Can't find file.
LogUObjectGlobals: Warning: Failed to find object 'Object /Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventsMasterFix.HorrorEventsMasterFix'
Warning:  applied to a non-external Texture2D sampler. This may work by chance on some platforms but is not portable. Please change sampler type to 'External'. Parameter 'Texture' (slot 0) in material 'HE_VhsGlow'
Warning:  applied to a non-external Texture2D sampler. This may work by chance on some platforms but is not portable. Please change sampler type to 'External'. Parameter 'Texture' (slot 0) in material 'HE_VhsGlow'
Warning:  applied to a non-external Texture2D sampler. This may work by chance on some platforms but is not portable. Please change sampler type to 'External'. Parameter 'Texture' (slot 0) in material 'HE_VhsGlow'
Warning:  applied to a non-external Texture2D sampler. This may work by chance on some platforms but is not portable. Please change sampler type to 'External'. Parameter 'Texture' (slot 0) in material 'HE_TvGlow'
Warning:  applied to a non-external Texture2D sampler. This may work by chance on some platforms but is not portable. Please change sampler type to 'External'. Parameter 'Texture' (slot 0) in material 'HE_TvGlow'
Warning:  applied to a non-external Texture2D sampler. This may work by chance on some platforms but is not portable. Please change sampler type to 'External'. Parameter 'Texture' (slot 0) in material 'HE_TvGlow'
PackagingResults: Warning: Error while enumerating Visual Studio toolchains
PackagingResults: Warning: Assuming no compilation capability for NET Framework projects.
PackagingResults: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventFix': Can't find file.
PackagingResults: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventFix': Can't find file.
PackagingResults: Warning: Failed to find object 'Object /Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventFix.HorrorEventFix'
PackagingResults: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventsMasterFix': Can't find file.
PackagingResults: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventsMasterFix': Can't find file.
PackagingResults: Warning: Failed to find object 'Object /Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/HorrorEvent/HorrorEventsMasterFix.HorrorEventsMasterFix'
PackagingResults: Warning: Saving FText "" which has been initialized from FString at cook time resave of source package /Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/SaveStructures/AssetsSave may fix issue.
PackagingResults: Warning: Saving FText "" which has been initialized from FString at cook time resave of source package /Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/SaveStructures/AssetsSave may fix issue.
PackagingResults: Warning: Saving FText "" which has been initialized from FString at cook time resave of source package /Game/HorrorEngine/Blueprints/Structures/SaveStructures/AssetsSave may fix issue
```